# jQuery unobtrusive validation dynamic content doesn't work anymore

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation, dynamic-content

I have content in a page loaded via Ajax. And the validation doesn't work.

I have tried various methods found in the net. Including:

```
var form = $("#myform").form.removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
```

Or:

```
$("#myInput").rules('add', {
required: true,
messages: { required: "The date is required" }
});
```

Or:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parseElement($("#myInput")[0]);
```

Or:

The famous xhalent at: https://xhalent.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/applying-unobtrusive-validation-to-dynamic-content/

Sad  to say that none of it work. It is year 2016 now. Samples found in jsfiddle also doesn't work anymore. Example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/LNjtd/2/
```

So, I believe there are some changes in either the browser / jQuery validation library that affected this.

I am using: MS Edge / IE11, jQuery 2.2.3, jQuery Val 1.15.0, jQuery unobtrusive val 3.2.3

Appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

Thanks in advance